# What is the value from AsInteger in delphi when dataset value is null?

Tags: delphi

I have this code in delphi:

```
var_beg := MyQry.FieldByName('x_beg').AsInteger;
var_end := MyQry.FieldByName('x_end').AsInteger;
x_segment := copy(name, var_beg, var_end - var_beg);
```

Now, in the table the columns `x_beg` and `x_end` are both nullable, and contain null values on some rows. My question is what values do the variables `var_beg` and `var_end` get when the columns `x_beg` and `x_end` are null?

Comment: Why can't you check this yourself? for all I remember it is 0.

Comment: @kobik coz what I am doing is just translating this delphi into C#, and I don't have any 'thing' where I can do delphi. Plus setting ups required to access database and all from delphi is very well beyond my delphi knowledge. And in fact I have started to hate delphi already.

Comment: AsInteger may be implemented differently for each TDataset descendant. please be more specific.

Comment: If you hate the way Delphi accesses databases then what will you do when you find out its much worse in c#

Comment: No reason to hate Delphi in this case. I think Delphi is quite easy to "read", compared to other languages. But it is not an easy task to convert the code if you are not familiar with Delphi. Maybe you hate thist job?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Null is automatically converted to 0 by `AsInteger` function (It's true for all dataset components I tried but you could have different behaviors using different `TField`'s descendants).

As [documentation](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DB_TField_AsInteger.html) says:

> Use AsInteger to read the value of the field's data into an integer,
>   or to assign an integer value to the contents of the field. TField
>   does not support integer values, and raises an exception when an
>   attempt is made to get or set the AsInteger property.

Conversion result depends on which `TField` descendant class your object is.
`TField.GetAsInteger` is a **virtual** function declared as follows:

```
function TField.GetAsInteger: Longint;
begin
  raise AccessError('Integer'); { Do not localize }
end;
```

If you need to check if the value is null you can use:

```
myField.AsVariant = Null
```

or

```
myField.IsNull
```

Comment: Thanks and I appreciate your help, but can you please add a reference link?

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ: I've updated my answer by adding a reference link (http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DB_TField_AsInteger.html)

Comment: Do not rely on these values. What's more, **you cannot cast NULL to a value** (if you'll rely on these default values and calculate e.g. average, you'll get an incorrect result).